# Redisson client injects weird characters at the beginning of strings

Tags: redis, redisson

I'm using Redisson client to publish String messages on a topic, but for some reasons, the published messages always contain some weird characters at the beginning:

eg: when I publish the string "{"event":"notification"}"
at the redis level I end up with this:
"\x04>\x18{"event":"notification"}"

```
1) "pmessage"
2) "*"
3) "active_project_users:1"
4) "\x04>\x18{\"event\":\"notification\"}"
```

Any idea how I can make those weird chars go away?

My java code looks like this:

```
 private void publish(String channel, String message) {       
        RTopic topic = redissonClient.getTopic(channel);
        topic.publish("{\"event\":\"notification\"}");
    }
```

I'm using redis:3.2 &  radisson-spring-boot-starter 3.16.1

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It seems I have to set the encoding for this to work properly:

```
RTopic topic = redissonClient.getTopic(channel, StringCodec.INSTANCE);
```